# How does HttpRequest.Query[] in .net core works?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest

How does the below statement work?

I tried to see in Microsoft documentation, but couldn't find much information

[Link to Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.query?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_Query)

`var queryString = this.Request.Query[SomeConstant.QueryString];`

Comment: Which part of `Gets the query value collection parsed from Request.QueryString.` is unclear to you? And I do not mean this snippy or sheepish. Is the word query and its meaning unclear or 'querystring'?

Comment: @Marco I dont understand this part `this.Request.Query[SomeConstant.QueryString];` I always get undefined in the queryString variable

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I understand that it value retrieval, but I don't understand why I always get 'undefined' into the variable even though Im passing a constant

Comment: Well, we cannot answer that, can we? What's the URL you're calling and what is the value of `SomeConstant.QueryString`? You need to [edit] your question and provide enough details.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I got to understand how it is working by below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you hit any of your endpoint with

`/someendpoint?foo=bar&name=Vamsi`

You can now get the whole QueryCollection with:

```
var queries = this.Request.Query;
```

If you want to retrieve a specific value by its key, you can use that:

```
var foo = this.Request.Query["foo"]   //value: bar
var name = this.Request.Query["name"] //value: Vamsi
```

So to answer your question: `Query[SomeConstant.QueryString]` is accessing the QueryCollection of the current request by accessing a specific key, that is stored in a variable called `SomeContant.QueryString`

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The query object here is an `IQueryCollection`.

The `IQueryCollection` implements both :

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,StringValues>>
IEnumerable
```

Suppose we have the following Url : http://localhost/home/index?code=A000

The key value pair you can see it as a dictionary, we have a key that represent the query string parameter name (ex: code) and we had a value (ex: A000)

In order to retrieve the code from the url, you have to search in that list and find this name. To do that, you call `Query["code"]`

In your case `SomeConstant.QueryString` is a constant defined somewhere in your projet in a class with name `SomeConstant` and a const with name `QueryString` and the value of this const is `"code"`.

```
public Class SomeConsant{
    public const string SomeConstant = "code";
}
```